# Android: How to make sliding buttons like phone unlock button on screensaver?

Tags: android, android-widget

I don't know how exactly this type of buttons is called that's why I can't even google about it.
You use that button to unlock phone - tap on it and move from left to right.
I'd like to add same button in my app. How to do it?

[image]

Comment: were you able to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use SeekBar to achieve what you want. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

Here is a good example

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/androids-seekbar-your-way/943

Comment: Yes I think it's similar to what I need. The only question I have is how to make my customized thumb to show long left part. Then you move the button from left to right you can see it's body on the left. How to achieve that?

Comment: In the progress_drawable.xml include the long part which will be shown when its dragged. In thumb_drawable.xml add the pointed kind of image which is to be dragged.

Comment: @Mik where you able to achieve this ? if yes please put out the code for me.. it would of great help

Comment: @anirudhmaddy - I want my seekbar to progress only when I drag the thumb and do nothing when i Click on the seekbar.. How to do it ? I used Android:clickable="false" but it didn't work

Comment: Hi,contactmeandroid. I ended up by writing my own component. I can give you a code if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a library
https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/SwipeButtonExample
and this for a DIY
https://rightclicksolutions.wordpress.com/2014/04/09/android-slide-to-unlock-like-ios-mb-slider-slider/

Answer (score 0):

You can overide onTouch() and change the location of the button acording to the x position. and when you lift the finger you can overide onUp()  (im not sure thats the name of the method) and create an animation that will lead the button back to its place.
From your question I get that you might think its a button you can simply add from a list of buttons, well, its not. you need to manualy create it.